# Pandas: For each Unique ID, iterate over a list of strings and print it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the below and I am trying to print the list of subjects for each unique ID.

```
 ID  Name    Subjects
  0  Tom    [maths,chem,history....]
  1  Harry  [biology,physics,maths...]
```

And then iterate over the length of the subject list to do different operations.

```
    for Subjects in ID:   
        print(Subjects)
    for idx in range(len(Subjects)):
        -- Do operations ---
```

I did this:

```
for df.Subjects in df.ID:
      print(df.Subjects)
```

But this printed ID Numbers.

Comment: but `df.ID` *this printed ID Numbers* - as it should. Synchronize code with your intention

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
for sub in df.ID:
  print(df.loc[sub]['Subjects'])
```